# Average close GPS coordinates

Tags: excel, vba, coordinates, average

im working on a macro to average all GPS coordinates that fall within a specified distance. I cant think of a way to loop through the list of coordinates to check if any of the other coordinates in the list are within 0.05 then average the coordinate.

I have played around using if statements and the distance between two coordinates formula

```
JoinD = Abs(((X1 - X2) ^ 2 + (Y1 - Y2) ^ 2) ^ 0.5)
matchdist=0.05    
If JoinD < matchdist Then..
```

Update: I have been tinkering around with the following logic and I think im on the right track

```
1cnt = 1
2cnt = 1
matchdist=0.05

For 1cnt = firstrow To lastcoordrow

X1 = Cells(1cnt, X1).Value
Y1 = Cells(1cnt, Y1).Value
Z1 = Cells(1cnt, Z1).Value

For 2cnt = firstrow To lastcoordrow

X2 = Cells(2cnt, X1).Value
Y2 = Cells(2cnt, Y1).Value
Z2 = Cells(2cnt, Z1).Value

joinD = Abs(((X1 - X2) ^ 2 + (Y1 - Y2) ^ 2) ^ 0.5)
    If joinD < matchdist And joinD > 0 Then
    
    sumX = sumX + X2
    sumY = sumY + Y2
    sumZ = sumZ + Z2
    
    noofmatches = noofmatches + 1

Next
```

Then after that have some logic that divides each sumX/sumy/sumZ value by the number of matches

But I cannot get anything working. the ideal result would be turning this data

unaveraged coords

[image]

into this data

averaged coords

[image]

Results from CDP1802 macro

[Results from CDP1802 macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmEcD.png)

Update for different id but within 0.05

[different id but within 0.05 data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahV9e.png)

Comment: Make another column that is rounded to 0.05, then group by that column, get avg etc...

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for your comment. it would be possible two coordinates to have the same X value but are further away than 0.05 which could mess up the order. Also, the issue I have is coming up with a method in VBA to search through the list, match, then average

Comment: Is the process to calculate average then check each against the average, eliminate the one with largest diff > 0.05 and then repeat calculation until all values are within 0.05 of their average ?

Comment: I think rounding both lat / lng to the nearest 0.05 would be the easiest solution. I would loop over the rows and calc "Euclidean distance" until you find no more rows to group up. But there's probably no easy solution for that in Excel or VBA.

Comment: @CDP1802 the process is to match all coordinates within 0.05 then average matched coordinates. All un averaged coordinates to be deleted once they have been averaged. Note that some coordinates may not have a match within 0.05

Comment: But what is the value you are matching each with ? How is the value determined ?

Comment: Trying to match all coordinates against all coordinates. I have thought of a possible solution and added it to the original question - still has some holes in it though

Comment: This seems like an interesting problem (and I don't have a solution), but wouldn't you first need to decide what the clusters are?  For example, I could straight-line GPS coordinates across the country with each being within 0.05 of the previous point, and there would be no point to averaging those points of a line.  On the other hand, I could  put points at 0.051 apart in a circle, and clearly they should be averaged, but wouldn't meet the criteria.  I think you need a clustering algorithm first to decide whether a point is in this group or that group. IMHO.

Comment: @wackojacko the formula to use would be "joinD = Abs(((X1 - X2) ^ 2 + (Y1 - Y2) ^ 2) ^ 0.5)  If joinD < matchdist And joinD > 0 Then " and use two "For"loops to test X1,Y1 v X2,Y2.

Comment: I apologize -- I did see that formula before.  How big is your actual list of GPS coordinates?  You basically need a matrix of n^2 to calculate `joinD` for every possibility, right?

Comment: @wackojacko yes, but just need the logic to do this in vba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group collections of co-ordinates into a dictionary and then loop though them calculating the average in a separate function.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Calc()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dict As Object, k, coord
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim id As String
    Dim x1 As Double, y1 As Double, z1 As Double
       
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
       
    Set ws = Sheets(1)
    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lastrow
             id = Trim(.Cells(i, "B"))
             x1 = .Cells(i, "C")
             y1 = .Cells(i, "D")
             z1 = .Cells(i, "E")
             
             If Len(id) > 0 And Not dict.exists(id) Then
                  dict.Add id, New Collection
             End If
             dict(id).Add Array(x1, y1, z1)
        Next
    End With
    
    ' result sheet2
    Dim rng As Range
    With Sheet2
        Set rng = .Cells(1, 1)
        For Each k In dict.keys
            id = CStr(k)
            coord = CalcAvg(dict(k))
            rng.Value = id
            rng.Offset(0, 1) = Format(coord(0), "0.000")
            rng.Offset(0, 2) = Format(coord(1), "0.000")
            rng.Offset(0, 3) = Format(coord(2), "0.000")
            rng.Offset(0, 4) = Format(coord(3), "0")
            Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
        Next
        .Columns("A:D").AutoFit
    End With
End Sub

Function CalcAvg(c As Collection) As Variant

    Const T = 0.05
    
    Dim x1 As Double, y1 As Double, z1 As Double
    Dim x As Double, y As Double, d As Double
    Dim xSum As Double, ySum As Double, zSum As Double
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
   
    ' calc average
    For i = 1 To c.Count
        x1 = c.Item(i)(0)
        y1 = c.Item(i)(1)
        z1 = c.Item(i)(2)

        For j = 1 To c.Count
            If i <> j Then
                x = Abs(x1 - c.Item(j)(0))
                y = Abs(y1 - c.Item(j)(1))
                
                ' check tolerance
                If x > T Or y > T Then
                   ' ignore
                Else
                    d = (x ^ 2 + y ^ 2) ^ 0.5
                    If d <= T Then
                        n = n + 1
                        xSum = xSum + x1
                        ySum = ySum + y1
                        zSum = zSum + z1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    If n > 0 Then
        CalcAvg = Array(xSum / n, ySum / n, zSum / n, c.count)
    ElseIf c.Count = 1 Then
        CalcAvg = Array(x1, y1, z1, 1)
    Else
        CalcAvg = Array(0, 0, 0, c.count)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Yeah, that's much better.  That's a full solution there.

Comment: This looks awesome. There are a few commands I don't understand so will do some research on them to see what they are doing (I'm only new to this). Thanks for your help. Does this print the averaged coordinates to the work sheet or just store them in an array?

Comment: @maran It writes the results to Sheet2. You can change `With Sheet2` to `With Sheets("sheet name")`

Comment: Hi CDP1802 - I have done some data testing on this code and it works fantastic! Is there a way to edit it so any coordinate that doesnt have a match within 0.05 (ie in this example RTCM-Ref) comes through with its original coordinate rather than 0,0,0?

Comment: @maran422 If you have only 1 coordinate then yes, but  suppose all the coords are more than 0.05 apart, which to chose ?

Comment: The assumption is that if they are more than 0.05m apart they are not the same point and shouldn't be averaged together. So if there are no other coordinates within 0.05 then that is the only coordinate for that point and it should come through in the final list of coordinates

Comment: @maran422 If you have 2 points and they cannot be averaged (more that 0.05 apart) then do you want the first one or the second one returned ?

Comment: @CDP1802 both, assuming that they dont match with any other coordinates listed. For example, in the above data RTCM-Ref only has one coordinate in the original list and is further than 0.05m away from any of the other coordinates in the list. When the macro is run its returns a coordinate of 0,0,0 when it would be best for it to return its original coordinate

Comment: @CDP1802 what is the data in column E? looks to be how many matches there are for each coordinate but B100 and B1 say 12 which they dont - see updated screen shot I have put in the original question

Comment: @CDP1802 B100 should be 4, B1 should also be 4. The macro returns the correct averaged coordinate however

Comment: @maran422 why 4 ? you have 4 coords so pairs are 4 x 3 = 12

Comment: @CDP1802 if there are 4 coordinates then shouldn't it return a value of 4? for example B103 has 4 coordinates and returns a value of 4 in column E, B35 has 2 coordinates and returns a value of 2 in E etc

Comment: @maran422 B103 has only 4 of the possible 12 pairs within the 0.05 limit. The 4th column is the same as `noofmatches` in your code. Do want the number of coordinates instead ?

Comment: @CDP1802 yes please, but shouldn't they be the same? both B100 & B103 have 4 coordinates within 0.05? really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: @maran Ok updated. B103 values are `430455.851,430455.863,430439.637,403439.618` so not all within 0.05. B100 are `430427.446,430427.429,430427.412,430427.423` so all ok.

Comment: Absolute legend thanks @CDP1802. Working flawlessly

Comment: @CDP1802 I have been using this code and its been working great. I have come across some data that have different id values (column B - B100, B102 etc) but are within 0.05m of each other and it doesn't average them. Is there a way that the macro can average these points that are within 0.05m but have different id values? I have added some new sample data - points GPS0001,GPS0002,GPS0003 are all within 0.05m but do not average. Ideally, the final averaged coordinate for these points could have an id of GPS0001

Comment: @maran are they always a single point per id.?

Comment: Not always. It depends on how I or someone else have coded/id the coordinates with the gps out in the field. In that latest example the same point was observed and coded/id 3 different times with different id's (GPS0001,GPS0002,GPS0003)

Comment: @maran Sorry, I don't have a answer yet. How can you identify the grouping without using the ID and how big would that group potentially be ?

Comment: @CDP1802 - dont apologise, you have been very helpful. 99% of the time the grouping will only be 2, on the odd occasion it would be more but should be less than 10. The ID is important, in the case that the ID differs but is within 0.05 the ID that gets pulled through for the averaged should be the 1st ID in the list - ie GPS0001, not GPS0002 or GPS0003. Dont worry if this cant be done, I can rename the IDs so they are the same before running the macro.

Answer (score 1):

## Partial answer

I'm curious where you go with this.

I made up some similar appearing data and built a matrix on a separate worksheet.  Maybe this gives you an idea where to go next, as I am not sure.

```
Option Explicit

Function joinD(X1 As Double, Y1 As Double, X2 As Double, Y2 As Double) As Double

joinD = Abs(((X1 - X2) ^ 2 + (Y1 - Y2) ^ 2) ^ 0.5)

End Function

Sub test_GPS()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim dist As Double

Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

Dim coord1() As Double
Dim coord2() As Double

lastrow = sh1.Range("D" & sh1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If lastrow > (sh2.Columns.Count - 3) Then Exit Sub 'This won't work if more data than columns exist.

ReDim coord1(1 To lastrow, 1 To 2)
ReDim coord2(1 To lastrow, 1 To 2)

With sh1.Range("D1:D" & lastrow)
    .Copy Destination:=sh2.Range("A2")
    .Copy
End With
sh2.Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False

For i = 1 To lastrow
    coord1(i, 1) = sh1.Range("B" & i).Value
    coord1(i, 2) = sh1.Range("C" & i).Value
    For j = 1 To lastrow
        coord2(j, 1) = sh1.Range("B" & j).Value
        coord2(j, 2) = sh1.Range("C" & j).Value
        
        dist = joinD(coord1(i, 2), coord1(i, 1), coord2(j, 2), coord2(j, 1))
        
        sh2.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value = dist
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

[image: Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 on my test script]

You'll almost certainly need to adjust that, but it's a starting point.  It's a possibility that I will have a similar need in the future for something like this, so I'm interested in whatever your final project looks like.